# What can go wrong when connecting a PSU?

Tags: power-supply

It will be my first time connecting a PSU. Could someone provide me a good tutorial of how to connect a modular PSU? Also, what's the worse that can happen if I connect something wrong? Can my PSU get damaged or something?

Comment: It's power, technically you could fry the PSU or anything it was connected too (such as the motherboard). Other than that, follow the instructions based upon the motherboard's manual as it should show you what you're connecting and where.

Comment: Just follow the instructions.  You have to try really hard or force a plug into the wrong connection.  The worst thing if you ignore the instructions and force something you will damage your hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't going to damage the PSU but you could damage other components if you don't connect them correctly. That being said, the plugs from the PSU usually only plug in one way. Plus, a good PSU will have each plug labelled as to what it is, its voltage, etc. I echo the above when I say refer to the manual of both the PSU and the motherboard/devices before you begin. Be careful to use safety precautions like a static wrist guard or at the very least be sure to discharge any static on metal before touching any components on the motherboard.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How should I test if the wires are connected properly? Should I turn on the computer only when everything is plugged? This PSU has more wires than it is needed, how do I determine how much I need?

Comment: My computer specifications:                                                  Motherboard: MB H77 S1155 MATX GA-Z77-DS3H                                   CPU: i7-3770 3.4 GHz                                                   Memory: 2x Kingston Beast 16GB DDR3 1600MHz KHX16C9T3K2/8X               Video card: GIGABYTE GV-N970G1 GAMING-4GD GeForce GTX 970 4GB         Hard drive: Samsung 500GB ST500DM005 SATA                             Optical drive: Samsung SH-224BB/BEBE